# I have to use excel to grab data from database to another worksheet

Tags: database, excel, product

My boss want me to do some sort of data grabber(in another worksheet). we have a database and we want to have another worksheet that has like a droplist with the products and then choosing a more specified product ( e.g. Camera > Dome Camera ) and by choosing that the prices and the modules numbers are automatically grabbed from the database.

Please help , i already made tables of all the data in the database. we have almost 20 tables but I really don't know how to refer to the whole table then choosing a column.

i need help for like what shall i do, which functions shall i use ?
what is the full process for such a thing ? , i need a sort of a brainstorming.

and no need for visual basics, i don't want to get into these codes too much.

Comment: @pnuts i searched them , we have 20 tables with 3 columns , how can i refer to the table then to the column ? e.g. ( Product type > Product's model ) ? i only can refer to the columns which is bad because i can't refer to the Pricelist in then with vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

it turned to be that i have to make couple of extra tables and name them. after breaking all the tables to many smaller tables everything make sense now